# What is better coding practice?

Tags: c#, optimization

What is better coding practice and why?

```
string str1 = textBox1.Text;
string str2 = textBox2.Text;
void FunctionName (str1, str2);
```

Or

```
void FunctionName(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. **This isn't optimization.**

Comment: It does matter if anyone else if ever going to take on the code.in the example shown, the second version is significantly easier to grok than the first example. If you were trying to soak up screen fulls of this stuff and it was all religiously done in the first way it would be much harder to absorb.

Comment: @Dave: That's definitely a matter of opinion. It's hardly universally valid to claim that the latter is easier to read or understand. (Just look at the answers here for confirmation!)

Comment: My comment really was a reaction to your 'It doesn't matter'. Good coding practice is more than just optimization - it (in my opinion) can include how other people read and react to your code. Since there's a difference of opinion, then the choice does matter ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think coding standards rules that enforce one approach over the other are often too draconian. I tend to use the approach that is most READABLE in each individual circumstance. That might even vary within the same method!

In the example you give, then I think the second option is actually more readable and understandable - it very clearly shows the relationship between the function call and the two controls.

In @O.D's example where extra things are being 'done' to the control values before they are passed in it becomes a little harder to see what's happening, and pulling 'confused' variables out and naming them in a way that explains what you're trying to achieve makes the code more readable (and self documenting).

Generally I'd say:

1. Start by putting everything directly into the method / function call
2. if any passed parameter has too long a call.path.to.get().to.the().value, consider pulling it out into it's own variable
3. if the line of code overall becomes too long, consider splitting the parameters onto one line each

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to declare separate variables when you don't plan to do anything with it. So I say the latter is better.

In the former example, you are doing unecassery work and adds more complexity to your code.

Now, if you plan to do some processing on those values, you could choose to use the former method. But you should give them more descriptive names than `str1` and `str2` to communicate their purpose.

Comment: And besides that, variable names like `str1` and `str2` are bad, because they don't say anything useful about what they hold.

Comment: @Steven: That's what I meant with my last sentence.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because why initialize a new variable when not needed.  I would think that would take a tad bit more time that just sending the value that has already been initialized somewhere else.  However if you need to perform for actions on the stings it would be best to assign them, do work, then set back.

Answer (score 4):

I would say the 1st Option is better, if anyone needs to do any operation on the String before passing it to the function he will tend to do this on the function call which causes nested calls over time which makes it more and more unreadable, as it would look like:

```
FunctionName(AnotherFunc(textBox1.Text), AnotherAnotherFunc(textBox2.Text));
```

etc.

having the string between makes it easier to make changes which stil readable.

Comment: A dissenter! I like your style. In such a completely trivial example, I think the second one is the obvious choice. But as you suggest, production code is rarely so trivial. +1

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd go with option 2, seeing as it has less code so it is easier to read and understand for another developer coming to the code (much) later on.

I'd imagine the compiler would optimise the first one into the second anyway (but I'm not sure that is true).

Comment: Nope. It actually "optimizes" the second into the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Form the performance point of view it will be the same because compiler will optimize it so it doesn't matter what practice you choose.

Answer (score 2):

The former version will be required in case you perform some sort of sanity check on the user input. For example, you could check the textbox text for `string.Empty`, etc. In your case, creating another variable does not make sense and it redundant.

From the point of view of .NET, the execution will not change as it will be optimized during the JIT.

For example,

```
string str1 = textBox1.Text.Trim();
string str2 = textBox2.Text.Trim();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str2))
{
    FunctionName (str1, str2);
}
```

or

```
string str1 = textBox1.Text.Trim();
string str2 = textBox2.Text.Trim();
if(ValidateInput(str1) && ValidateInput(str2))
{
    FunctionName (str1, str2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First off it doesn't make a difference in regard to speed of processing. Both will take the same amount of time.  Option2 is the one i would choose as it is easier to read IMO.

In certain situations it is useful to place values into variables simply to allow you to place a breakpoint on them when you are debugging code.  It doesn't really apply to this example but there are situations where i would choose option1 just for this reason.